# Google Data Studio - Pie chart by range

Tags: looker-studio

I have a column with values ranging from 0 to 100:

[image]

And I am trying to make a pie chart by the total in a range, Example : 0 - 20, 20 - 40, 40 - 60 and so on...

Already tried adding new fields having formula, but didn't work.

Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a new field with this formula (adapt it for your needs):

```
CASE
  WHEN reliability >= 0  AND reliability <  20  THEN '0 - 19'
  WHEN reliability >= 20 AND reliability <  40  THEN '20 - 39'
  WHEN reliability >= 40 AND reliability <  60  THEN '40 - 59'
  WHEN reliability >= 60 AND reliability <  80  THEN '60 - 79'
  WHEN reliability >= 80 AND reliability <= 100 THEN '80 - 100'
  ELSE 'out of range'
END
```

Then, select this field as dimension in your Pie Chart.  Easy Peasy.